# HTML5 Gradient isn't working Correctly for some colors

Tags: html, linear-gradients

So I'm trying to get my gradient working on my HTML tag so it shows in the background but I noticed certain colors show off as more blocky than others. I want the whole background to be a gradient and after researching (here and other sites) I got this far but it looks like multiple blocks instead of a gradient like other colors seem to have. How can I fix this so the whole background doesn't move when scrolling and doesn't show blocks? I've only ever used gradients in scripts before so I don't like using it.

I found [this as a close solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031330/rectangular-gradient-with-html5-canvas-element) but I'm trying to avoid scripts at all costs as mentioned above.

```css
html 
{
 min-height: 100%; /*needed for no repeat color. adding normal "height" messes it up*/
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background: #FFA5A5; /* Older browsers */
 background: linear-gradient(#FFA5A5, #FFFFFF);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFA5A5 0%,#FFFFFF 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FFA5A5), color-stop(100%,#FFFFFF)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFA5A5 0%,#FFFFFF 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFA5A5 0%,#FFFFFF 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFA5A5 0%,#FFFFFF 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top, #FFA5A5 0%,#FFFFFF 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFA5A5', endColorstr='#FFFFFF',GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>t</title>
  <meta name="description" content="c">
  <meta name="author" content="a">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GBG.css">
 </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't look blotchy to me. Seems like you have a problem with graphic card drivers.

Comment: not blotchy, blocky. it's harder to see on the smaller image but it's there. I see this on 2 computers and mobile. So I don't think it's that

Comment: I can't see any blocks in your snippet. Maybe you could share a screenshot?

Comment: It's working now on all devices and I made 0 changes. So I guess it was something else. Thank you so much for the help tho!